# I want removed the input image and matching lines, added a line to show the center of the bounding rectangle

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am working in android studio 2.3.1

I want removed the input image and matching lines, added a line to show the center of the bounding rectangle

Object Tracking using OpenCV

I have core java

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {

private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";
private int w, h;
private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
Scalar RED = new Scalar(255, 0, 0);
Scalar GREEN = new Scalar(0, 255, 0);
FeatureDetector detector;
DescriptorExtractor descriptor;
DescriptorMatcher matcher;
Mat descriptors2,descriptors1;
Mat img1;
MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1,keypoints2;

static {
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug())
        Log.d("ERROR", "Unable to load OpenCV");
    else
        Log.d("SUCCESS", "OpenCV loaded");
}

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                try {
                    initializeOpenCVDependencies();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;
            default: {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
};

private void initializeOpenCVDependencies() throws IOException {
    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
    detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.FAST);
    descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);
    matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);
    img1 = new Mat();
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream istr = assetManager.open("test.png");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, img1);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img1, img1, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    img1.convertTo(img1, 0); //converting the image to match with the type of the cameras image
    descriptors1 = new Mat();
    keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
    descriptor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);

}


public MainActivity() {

    Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1_activity_java_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
        mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
    }
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    w = width;
    h = height;
}

public void onCameraViewStopped() {
}

public Mat recognize(Mat aInputFrame) {

    Imgproc.cvtColor(aInputFrame, aInputFrame, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    descriptors2 = new Mat();
    keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    detector.detect(aInputFrame, keypoints2);
    descriptor.compute(aInputFrame, keypoints2, descriptors2);

    // Matching
    MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
    if (img1.type() == aInputFrame.type()) {
        matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);
    } else {
        return aInputFrame;
    }
    List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();

    Double max_dist = 0.0;
    Double min_dist = 100.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < matchesList.size(); i++) {
        Double dist = (double) matchesList.get(i).distance;
        if (dist < min_dist)
            min_dist = dist;
        if (dist > max_dist)
            max_dist = dist;
    }

    LinkedList<DMatch> good_matches = new LinkedList<DMatch>();
    for (int i = 0; i < matchesList.size(); i++) {
        if (matchesList.get(i).distance <= (1.5 * min_dist))
            good_matches.addLast(matchesList.get(i));
    }

    MatOfDMatch goodMatches = new MatOfDMatch();
    goodMatches.fromList(good_matches);
    Mat outputImg = new Mat();
    MatOfByte drawnMatches = new MatOfByte();
    if (aInputFrame.empty() || aInputFrame.cols() < 1 || aInputFrame.rows() < 1) {
        return aInputFrame;
    }
    Features2d.drawMatches(img1, keypoints1, aInputFrame, keypoints2, goodMatches, outputImg, GREEN, RED, drawnMatches,Features2d.NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);
    Imgproc.resize(outputImg, outputImg, aInputFrame.size());

    return outputImg;
}

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    return recognize(inputFrame.rgba());

    }
}
```

PS:I haven't provided any code, since I don't really know what to provide. I would be more than happy to provide some if needed

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You'll need to provide more information about what you mean by `I want to frame the desired object`. The fact that you've dumped some code and provided a link to an image doesn't help define your problem. Please edit your question and improve your description of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Helpppp me plsss